# How do I change recording framerate of a webcamera in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, usb, video-capture, frame-rate, webcam-capture

I would like to know how I can record a video and how to change the recording framerate in MATLAB with my webcam using Support Package for USB Webcams (not using toolboxes, including Image Acquisition tool box). I am thinking about using it because that package is free.

The code I made is like the below. I tried to set 2 frames/sec (fps) by `v.FrameRate=2` but that code doesn't work (the recorded framerate was about 15 fps and the recording ended on about 10 sec), and I was not able to change fps in this way. Does my webcam work in Matlab Support Package for USB Webcams? How do I solve it?

```
function webcam_recordingvideo()
cam = webcam;
preview(cam)  
v = VideoWriter('frames.avi');
get(v);
v.FrameRate=2;
open(v);
frames = 150; % frame number to get
for i = 1:frames
img = snapshot(cam); % Acquire frame for processing
writeVideo(v, img); % Write frame to video
end
close(v);
clear cam
```

I'm using Matlab 2016a and Logitech HD Webcam C615.

Comment: Could it be that your for-loop is simply running at full speed, which on your hardware results in ~15fps? Try adding a delay of 500ms in the for-loop.

Comment: The pause function during loop may be helpful. I'll try it.Thank you!

Comment: So did you actually use `pause(30)` to solve it?